# Spotify Play Button width and height locked to arbitrary aspect ratio

Tags: spotify

I noticed that I cannot choose any width and height combo I want for the Spotify Play Button. If I use the generator tool and increase the width, it automatically increases the height field to match some arbitrary aspect ratio. So, I can never truly get the exact width and height I need (even within the min and max values specified on the developer page).

What I need is a width of 440px and height of 720px. When I set the width and height in the iframe to 440 x 720, it actually renders at 440 x 520.

Any plans to fix?

Comment: Are there Spotify developers here? What's the word on this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to customize the spotify play button.
I solved the problem by passing a custom style to the iframe object :

```
style="width:480px; height:480px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:21px;"
```

for instance :

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:sharemyplaylists.com:playlist:0QoIyI6lLs5IfZMjOf5aNK&amp;theme=white" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width:600px; height:680px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:21px;"></iframe>
```

I know it's not documented that way, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is actually a bug; you could - as jackj4ck says - add the style attribute to the embed code or simply change the height and width attributes that the embed code gives you.

EG:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Would become:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs" width="440" height="720" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```